# Как в одном цикле вместить несколько telebot-кнопок в одном ряду?

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Имеется код

```
timeslots = [
    '00:00', '00:30', '01:00', '01:30', '02:00', '02:30', '03:00', '03:30', '04:00', '04:30',
    '05:00', '05:30', '06:00', '06:30', '07:00', '07:30', '08:00', '08:30', '09:00', '09:30',
    '10:00', '10:30', '11:00', '11:30', '12:00', '12:30', '13:00', '13:30', '14:00', '14:30',
    '15:00', '15:30', '16:00', '16:30', '17:00', '17:30', '18:00', '18:30', '19:00', '19:30',
    '20:00', '20:30', '21:00', '21:30', '22:00', '22:30', '23:00', '23:30'
]

available_timeslots = []

for timeslot in timeslots:
    if timeslot in available_slots:
        available_timeslots.append('✅ ' + timeslot)
    else:
        available_timeslots.append(timeslot)

mes = 'Выберите дату и нажмите нужное время, чтобы записаться'
keyboard = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
keyboard.row_width = 5

for timeslot in available_timeslots:
    keyboard.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=timeslot, callback_data='Time' + timeslot))

keyboard.add(
    telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Пред.', callback_data='back'),
    telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=user.date_enroll, callback_data='date_now'),
    telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='След.', callback_data='next')
)

bot.send_message(chat_id, mes, reply_markup=keyboard)

user.step = 'enroll'
user.save()
return HttpResponse('OK')
```

Цикл воспроизводит кнопки вертикально каждую по отдельности в ряд
[image: к]

Как я могу его изменить, чтобы получилось по несколько штук в один ряд?

Вот пример кода, чтоб было понятнее

```
keyboard.add(
    telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="00:00", callback_data="Time00:00"),
    telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="00:30", callback_data="Time00:30"),
    telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="01:00", callback_data="Time01:00"),
    telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="01:30", callback_data="Time01:30"),
    telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="02:00", callback_data="Time02:00"),
    telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="02:30", callback_data="Time02:30"),
    telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="03:00", callback_data="Time03:00"),
    telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="03:30", callback_data="Time03:30"),
    ...
)
```

Результат получается следующим:

[image: й]

Comment: А ваш пример, чтобы понятнее было, по одной кнопке в ряд добавляет?

Comment: @gil9red да, по одной

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Честно скажу, что не знаком с telebot, но может сработать

```
# задаем количество кнопок на строку
buttons_in_row = 2
buttons_added = []

for timeslot in available_timeslots:
    # добавляем элементы в список, который будет будущей строкой
    buttons_added.append(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=timeslot, callback_data='Time' + timeslot))

    # проверяем размер списка
    if len(buttons_added) == buttons_in_row:
        # если размер равен количеству кнопок в строке, то добавляем на форму используя распаковку аргументов
        keyboard.add(*buttons_added)
        buttons_added = []

# проверяем осталось ли что-то в списке, если да, то добавляем
if buttons_added:
    print(*buttons_added)
```